# Excel VBA How to capture filename from opened file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a code where we copy and paste data from an excel file that's already open.

Given that file has multiple version and can directly open from email its resulting to this.

Version 1 Filename: Excel Data.csv
Version 2 Filename:Excel Data (2).csv
Version 3 Filename:Excel Data (3).csv

I was wondering if there's a code where VBA can search for the file name based on existing keyword "Excel Data" or just "Excel" so the window will go to that file then I can perform copy and paste

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have Excel loop through all open workbooks and find one with the correct name. You can put something like this in your code.

```
Sub ActivateWorkbookByName(sName)

    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like "*" & sName & "*" Then
            wb.Activate
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wb

End Sub
```